# Search Column for Value from another Column

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and I am trying to solve a problem to which I can't find the answer to on here.

I have 3 columns of data,
which you can see here:

[image]

I want to write a macro with which I can search the first fruit of column D in A. If the macro finds a match I want to copy the property of the fruit (B)(e.g. Vegetable) to E next to the corresponding name.

An example:
D6=Pineapple
search for pineapple in A and then copy B4 (Fruit) to E2.
Then continue with D3 (Avocado) doing the same procedure.

This is what I came up with so far. I know it is terrible and it doesn't work at all :')

```
Option Explicit

Sub fruits()

Dim fruit As String
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

Do While i < 20


    Set fruit = Cells(i, "D").Value

    If Not fruit Is Nothing Then

    Set Cells(i, "E") = Columns(1).find(fruit.Value).Offset(0, 1).Text

    End If

  i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

If you have any advice or solutions I would really appreciate it.

Sorry that I am posting such a 'trivial' question, but I really don't know how to.

Thanks, NiceRice

Comment: Why not just use VLOOKUP?

Comment: in E1 `=VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE)` and copy down.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your help!! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim rng as range, rng2 as range, rcell as range, rcell2 as range
set rng = Thisworkbook.sheets("sheetName").range("d1:d3")
set rng2 = Thisworkbook.sheets("sheetName").range("a1:a8")

for each rcell in rng.cells
    if rcell.value <> vbNullstring then
        for each rcell2 in rn2.cells
            If rcell.value = rcell2.value then
                rcell.offset(0,1).value = rcell2.value  
            end if      
        next rcell2
    end if
next rcell
```

pretty straight forward

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Scott Craner, using Vlookup is the way to go, but I thought I would share a slightly different way to accomplish the same in VBA using the Find method:

```
Option Explicit

Sub fruits()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastARow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastDRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column D
LastARow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, FoundVal As Range

Set rng = ws.Range("D1:D" & LastDRow)

For Each c In rng
    Set FoundVal = ws.Range("A1:A" & LastARow).Find(What:=c.Value)
    If Not FoundVal Is Nothing Then
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = FoundVal.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much for taking to answer my question! I am really very greatful!!! I read your code and really learned a lot from it. I am sure the knowledge I gained will come in handy in future!!